# remove fields on checkout page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How do I remove fields on the Woocommerce Checkout page?

I read on [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) page that it can be done with a filter - tried it but it didn't work (I changed `order_comments` by `billing_phone` which is one of the fields I'd like to hide.

```php
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);

     return $fields;
}
```

How can I hide the telephone field, for example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the phone field with this filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);

     return $fields;
}
```

Be sure to add this in the file function.php of your current theme.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);

     return $fields;
}
```

That maybe?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26260114)

Comment: I made it more complete, tnx